# Vue how to solve Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to create a simple web app with authentication via Telegram. Telegram has it's own widget with callback which returns you user data after logging in. And the problem is in the script attribute "data-onauth" here you pass the callback you want to execute after success auth.

( https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login - widget documentation if you need it )

To locate log in button in the place you want you just need to paste script given by Telegram's widget generator, but since I can't paste script tag in components template ( vue just won't compile it & just return you error ) I chose to create script element add needed attributes and append it in mounted().

Here is my component code

```
<template>
  <header>
      <div class="auth" id="telegramAuth">
      </div>
  </header>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Header",
  data: () => ({}),
  mounted() {
    let telegramAuth = document.createElement("script");
    telegramAuth.setAttribute("async", "");
    telegramAuth.setAttribute(
      "src",
      "https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?7"
    );

    telegramAuth.setAttribute("data-userpic", "false");
    telegramAuth.setAttribute("data-telegram-login", "t_adv_bot");
    telegramAuth.setAttribute("data-size", "large");
    telegramAuth.setAttribute("data-onauth", this.loginWithTelegram);
    telegramAuth.setAttribute("data-request-access", "write");
    document.querySelector("#telegramAuth").appendChild(telegramAuth);
  },
  methods: {
    loginWithTelegram: function onTelegramAuth(user) {
        console.log(user);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

But when I try to do so I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name.
And I don't know how to solve it. Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor English

Comment: your `data-onauth` will have the string value `function onTelegramAuth(user) {
        console.log(user);
    }` ... the example in the documentation is `onTelegramAuth(user)` - you can see the difference is significant

Answer (score 1):

```
  methods: {
    loginWithTelegram(user) {
     console.log(user);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I got that problem is in unnecessary "function" but I did exactly as wrote above and It didn't work for me. Error is the same. I guess I can solve it with just saving function as a string but do you have any ideas how make it in any other way. Parsing function to string using .toString() also isn't a good idea because that's what I get after function () { [native code] } and its either don't has a function name.